# How to order pods based on the nodes in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `kubernetes` cluster working perfectly fine. It has 5 worker nodes. I am using below command to get the status of pods.

```
kubectl get pod -o wide --namespace=machines
```

which shows below results

```
NAME                  READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP        NODE
deployment-26hfn      0/4       ContainerCreating   0          5m        <none>    machine003
deployment-782mk      0/4       Pending             0          5m        <none>    machine001
deployment-7kcc7      0/4       Pending             0          5m        <none>    machine002
deployment-8fzqs      0/4       ContainerCreating   0          5m        <none>    machine004
deployment-zfzts      0/4       ContainerCreating   0          5m        <none>    machine005
```

As you can see, the above result is not in order from `machine001` to `machine 005`. Is it possible to print the output like below:

```
NAME                  READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       IP        NODE
deployment-26hfn      0/4       Pending   0          5m        <none>    machine001
deployment-782mk      0/4       Pending             0          5m        <none>    machine002
deployment-7kcc7      0/4       ContainerCreating   0          5m        <none>    machine003
deployment-8fzqs      0/4       ContainerCreating   0          5m        <none>    machine004
deployment-zfzts      0/4       ContainerCreating   0          5m        <none>    machine005
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can pipe the kubectl command output to sort:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --namespace=machines | sort -k7
```

or to omit the first line

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --namespace=machines | sed -n '1!p' | sort -k7
```

Also, you should be able to do this by `--sort-by` option in kubectl:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --sort-by=.spec.nodeName
```

Comment: The advantage of the second, aside from being simple and likely faster through reduce shell forking, is that it leaves the header row at the top of the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension [KUBEBSORT](https://github.com/AATHITH/kubesort)  to simplify the sorting process. Have a try.